# UIView animateWithDuration behaves differently on iOS 13

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation, ios13

The following code was working successfully till iOS12.2, which was sliding up the calendar grid until it's hidden.

```
 -(void) hideCalendarGrid {


     [UIView animateWithDuration:10.0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent animations:^{ //iwashere animation wrong iOS13. duration set to 10.0 for testing originally it was 0.2

         CGRect collectionViewRect   = self.collectionView.frame;
         collectionViewRect.origin.y -= collectionViewRect.size.height;
         self.collectionView.frame   = collectionViewRect;

         CGRect tableViewRect        = self.tableView.frame;
         tableViewRect.origin.y      -= collectionViewRect.size.height;
         tableViewRect.size.height   += collectionViewRect.size.height;
         self.tableView.frame        = tableViewRect;

     } completion:^(BOOL finished){
         if (finished) {
             // Reset frame but make it invisible
             self.collectionView.hidden = YES;
             self.collectionView.frame = self.collectionViewRectWhenVisible;
             self.collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0.0f;
             self.isCalendarOn = NO;
             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"isCalendarOn"];
             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
             [self configureNavigationBar];
             self.backButton.enabled = YES;
             self.backButton.hidden  = NO;
             if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"doneTutorial3.0CalendarGrid"]) {
                 [self showHowToHideCalendarGridTutorial];
             }
         }
     }];
 }
```

Demo on iOS 12.2 (works as expected)
https://youtu.be/sU5rbnujh3U

Demo on iOS 13 (not the way I want)
https://youtu.be/mk3AFsh5FCw

Does anyone know how to make the animation work like iOS12 on iOS13?

Comment: What if you delete UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent?

Comment: hi, did you find any solution to this issue? @tsuyoski

Answer (score 1):

You can change **self.collectionView.layer.frame** and **self.tableView.layer.frame** in animations block also like this:

self.collectionView.layer.frame = collectionViewRect;

self.tableView.layer.frame = tableViewRect;

**so your code maybe like this:**

```
-(void) hideCalendarGrid {


 [UIView animateWithDuration:10.0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent animations:^{ //iwashere animation wrong iOS13. duration set to 10.0 for testing originally it was 0.2

     CGRect collectionViewRect   = self.collectionView.frame;
     collectionViewRect.origin.y -= collectionViewRect.size.height;
     self.collectionView.frame   = collectionViewRect;
     // code for iOS 13
     self.collectionView.layer.frame   = collectionViewRect;

     CGRect tableViewRect        = self.tableView.frame;
     tableViewRect.origin.y      -= collectionViewRect.size.height;
     tableViewRect.size.height   += collectionViewRect.size.height;
     self.tableView.frame        = tableViewRect;
     // code for iOS 13
     self.tableView.layer.frame = tableViewRect;

 } completion:^(BOOL finished){
     if (finished) {
         // Reset frame but make it invisible
         self.collectionView.hidden = YES;
         self.collectionView.frame = self.collectionViewRectWhenVisible;
         self.collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0.0f;
         self.isCalendarOn = NO;
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"isCalendarOn"];
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
         [self configureNavigationBar];
         self.backButton.enabled = YES;
         self.backButton.hidden  = NO;
         if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"doneTutorial3.0CalendarGrid"]) {
             [self showHowToHideCalendarGridTutorial];
         }
     }
 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this the following way. Just changing the timing of setting table height depending on iOS version.

```
 -(void) hideCalendarGrid {


     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent animations:^{

         CGRect collectionViewRect   = self.collectionView.frame;
         self.collectionViewRectTemp = self.collectionView.frame; 
         collectionViewRect.origin.y -= collectionViewRect.size.height;
         self.collectionView.frame   = collectionViewRect;
    
         if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
             // iOS 13 DO NOT CHANGE TABLE HEIGHT YET
             CGRect tableViewRect        = self.tableView.frame;
             tableViewRect.origin.y      -= collectionViewRect.size.height;
             self.tableView.frame        = tableViewRect;
         } else {
             // iOS 12 and earlier CHANGE TABLE Y AND HEIGHT
             CGRect tableViewRect        = self.tableView.frame;
             tableViewRect.origin.y      -= collectionViewRect.size.height;
             tableViewRect.size.height   += collectionViewRect.size.height;
             self.tableView.frame        = tableViewRect;
         }

     } completion:^(BOOL finished){
         if (finished) {

             if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
                 // iOS 13 CHANGE TABLE HEIGHT NOW
                 CGRect tableViewRect        = self.tableView.frame;
                 tableViewRect.size.height   += self.collectionViewRectTemp.size.height;
                 self.tableView.frame        = tableViewRect;
             }

             // Reset frame but make it invisible
             self.collectionView.hidden = YES;
             self.collectionView.frame = self.collectionViewRectWhenVisible;
             self.collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0.0f;
             self.isCalendarOn = NO;
             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"isCalendarOn"];
             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
             [self configureNavigationBar];
             self.backButton.enabled = YES;
             self.backButton.hidden  = NO;
         }
     }];
 }
```